# need working Apache POI 3.8 osgi bundle for Apache karaf 2.2.8

Tags: osgi, apache-poi, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle

I am using Karaf 2.2.8 , inside my code I am reading and excel file using apache poi

```
try{

Workbook wb=WorkbookFactory.create(inp);

}
```

the application was working fine in tomcat 6 and tomcat 7 using poi-ooxml-3.8.jar

in karaf 2.2.8 :-

***when using servicemix bundles gives me

```
ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory not found by org.apache.servicemix.bundles.poi
```

***when using apache poi

```
Unable to resolve 266.0: missing requirement [266.0] package; (package=org.apache.poi))
```

commands used to install servicemix poi :-

```
install -s mvn:avalon-framework/avalon-framework/4.1.3;
install -s mvn:junit/junit/3.8.2;
install -s mvn:commons-codec/commons-codec/1.5;
install -s mvn:commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1;
install -s mvn:javax.servlet/servlet-api/2.3;
install -s mvn:log4j/log4j/1.2.13;
install -s mvn:logkit/LogKit/1.2;
install -s mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.poi/3.8_1;
```

commands used to install apache poi:-

```
install -s mvn:org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml/3.8;
install -s mvn:org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml-schemas/3.8;
install -s mvn:org.apache.poi/poi/3.8;
install -s mvn:commons-codec/commons-codec/1.5;
install -s mvn:dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1;
install -s mvn:stax/stax-api/1.0.1;
install -s mvn:org.apache.xmlbeans/xmlbeans/2.3.0;
```

any help please

Comment: I figured it out.
I didn't have to put apache poi as an osgi bundle. I added it to the "Lib" directory inside karaf and exported the needed packages as following :-

karaf.home/etc/custom.properties 

    karaf.systemBundlesStartLevel=50
     ...
      com.sun.jndi.ldap; \
      oracle.jdbc; \
      org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel; \
      org.apache.poi;

now it's working great

Comment: You should probably post that as an answer rather than a comment, so it's easier for other people coming across your post to spot what the fix is

Comment: I don't recommend placing these kinds of jars into the lib folder. For you it is probably more easier to place those jars into your application bundle.

Comment: Yes Achim you are right, I should add it as a bundle ... but karaf doesn't expose the packages of the jar correctly and the bundled versions of sevicemix and springsource of apache poi is old and doesn't support docx & xlsx

Comment: He means you should embed the jar into your bundle.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I didn't have to put apache poi as an osgi bundle. 
I added it to the "Lib" directory inside karaf and exported

the needed packages as following :-

```
karaf.home/etc/custom.properties 
karaf.systemBundlesStartLevel=50 
... 
com.sun.jndi.ldap; \ 
oracle.jdbc; \ 
org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel; \ 
org.apache.poi;
```

now it's working great

Comment: It seems your solution is not working for me. Please find the error below:
Error executing command: Could not start bundle mvn: in feature(s): Unresolved constraint in bundle  [306]: Unable to resolve 306.0: missing requirement [306.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.poi
.xssf.usermodel)